# Generate li elements for bootstrap pagination dinamically so they respond to onclick events

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, pagination

I'm having problems to make work a BootStrap pagination where the list elements are dynamically generated. I can generate the list elements, but they don't seem to respond to events, like when the user clicks them.

Let me give you two examples to better illustrate my problem:

1) This code works. Here I'm using a static pagination, where all my list items are already created. As you can see when I click an element of the pagination, the elements gets activated.

https://jsfiddle.net/2040n6a2/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>

<nav id="pag_nav">
  <ul class="pagination">
  <li class=prev><a href=# aria-label=Previous><span aria-hidden=true>&laquo;</span></a></li>
      <li><a href=#>1</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>2</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>3</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>4</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>5</a></li>
      <li class=next><a href=# aria-label=Previous><span aria-hidden=true>&raquo;</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

var pageItem = $('.pagination > li').not('.prev,.next');
var prev = $('.pagination > li.prev');
var next = $('.pagination > li.next');

pageItem.click(function() {
  pageItem.removeClass('active');
    $(this).not('.prev,.next').addClass('active');
});

next.click(function() {
   $('li.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
});

prev.click(function() {
   $('li.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
});
```

2) This code doesn't work. Here I'm creating the list elements dynamically. In this case, when I click an element of the pagination, the elements don't get activated.

https://jsfiddle.net/n75d2vct/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>

<nav id="pag_nav">
  <ul class="pagination">
  </ul>
</nav>

</body>

var pageItem = $('.pagination > li').not('.prev,.next');
var prev = $('.pagination > li.prev');
var next = $('.pagination > li.next');

pageItem.click(function() {
  pageItem.removeClass('active');
    $(this).not('.prev,.next').addClass('active');
});

next.click(function() {
   $('li.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
});

prev.click(function() {
   $('li.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
});

$('#pag_nav ul').append('<li class=prev><a href=# aria-label=Previous><span aria-hidden=true>&laquo;</span></a></li>');

for (var i = 0; i <5; i++)
{
    $('#pag_nav ul').append('<li><a href=#>' + i + '</a></li>');
}

$('#pag_nav ul').append('<li class=next><a href=# aria-label=Previous><span aria-hidden=true>&raquo;</span></a></li>');
```

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong on my second example?. I know I can use well known plug-ins like Datatables but I want to understand why using plain BootStrap + jQuery my code is not working.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Go read up on the keyword _event delegation_.

Comment: @Cardelco As CBroe says, event delegation is what you want here. For your case, you want to you use JQuery's 'on':
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You could use `on` as others have suggested but really all you need to do is generate the markup before setting event handlers. It's not working because you're setting your event handlers on elements that haven't been generated yet. [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n75d2vct/1/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v14t257h/, like the comments below say: You have to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

If you want to draw dynamically your pagination, the code should look something like this

```
$('.pagination').on('click', 'li:not(.prev):not(.next)', function() {
    $('.pagination li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).not('.prev,.next').addClass('active');
});

$('.pagination').on('click', 'li.prev', function() {
    $('li.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
});

$('.pagination').on('click', 'li.next', function() {
    $('li.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
});

function drawPagination(numOfPages) {
    $('#pag_nav ul').empty();
    $('#pag_nav ul').append('<li class=prev><a href=# aria-label=Previous><span aria-hidden=true>&laquo;</span></a></li>');
   for (var i = 1; i <= numOfPages; i++) {
      $('#pag_nav ul').append('<li><a href=#>' + i + '</a></li>');
   }
   $('#pag_nav ul').append('<li class=next><a href=# aria-label=Previous><span aria-hidden=true>&raquo;</span></a></li>');
}

drawPagination(5);
```